# Inquire about allowance increment?

Tags: professionalism, salary

The company I intern at supports my higher education and at the same time pays me an allowance every month.

According to my contract with the company, my allowance would be incremented slightly every year. Its been over 6 months since I completed one year, but there's been no increment in the allowance.

My peers urge me to to inquire about this matter (I believe they already have) because they too have not received the promised increment.

To be honest I don't care for the slight increment because I am very grateful my company supports my education and I don't feel comfortable discussing allowances.

So my question is; what is the best way to handle this situation so that I don't upset my peers or the management?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What country are you in that lets you "intern" for 1.5 years?

Comment: @enderland it's pretty common in the U.S.  Some companies even have unpaid interns for several years.  Co-ops are more common with extended time.  Sometimes co-ops even go for 2-3 years, with a semester in college and a semester on the job.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you've been promised an increment and you haven't got it, then it is entirely reasonable to ask about it. Ask your boss or HR. This is especially true if there are documents (emails, letters etc.) promising you an increment.

If you really don't want to ask, there is no need to be pressured by your peers into asking. You can politely tell them you would rather not ask. Tell them why if you like. They are just as capable of asking as you, and if they want the increment they can do it.

**However**...asking about things you have been promised but haven't been delivered is a useful skill in the workplace (and a fairly basic one). If doing so makes you uncomfortable, now is an excellent time to practice. Better to try it now, on something that isn't that important to you, than later in your career for something that is important. It's very unlikely that asking will have any bad effects on your career - but it will expand your comfort zone.

Answer (score 0):

If there are published documents indicating the increment, you should bring it up with your Human Resources (HR) department, and mention the documents. If there are no published documents indicating the increment then I would be tempted to not inquire.

Comment: A verbal contract is still a contract, just harder to enforce. There is no reason not to inquire politely just because you don't have a piece of paper that says so, just be aware that if they deny it, then going on a crusade is going to look bad on yourself as there is no physical evidence